# Google backup issues after factory reset: required to enter the Google account last synced

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, rca-voyager

I recently purchased a RCA Voyager tablet from someone off of Craigslist. I'm trying to set it up as they factory reset it but it says I have to enter the Google account last synced to the device. I have no way of getting that info as I don't have the contact number of the person anymore. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset doesn't ask for that, so there is something amiss.  Somehow it is not doing a real factory reset.  Try powering it up while holding the volume up (+) button.

Mine was really easy.  Just went to the settings menu and all it did was ask if I was sure.

When you do log it into your Google account it will find any and all Android devices you have sync'd and it will ask you which one you want to restore into the unit.

Comment: Unfortunately, factory reset *does* ask for this indeed, it's called "factory reset protection" and was introduced somewhere around Marshmallow. It gets triggered whenever you forgot to manually remove your Google account prior to performing a factory reset. See our [factory-reset tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for further details.

Comment: I use my Viking Pro with Android 5.0 daily - bought it used - and when I did it, it simply asked if I was sure, then wiped everything.  I logged in and it installed all the apps I had been using on my Alcatel smartphone.  I suppose it is possible the previous user never used Google, but that seems rather unlikely.  In any case, search around for a user guide, or try to contact them.  For me, the factory reset is simply a factory reset.  No muss, no fuss.

Comment: After doing some searching around, I see the recommendation to power it down, then hold the volume up button as you power it up.  There are videos posted on this, too.  I didn't have to do any of that.  But check out Google - search for "rca viking pro factory reset"

Comment: You're talking Lollipop (Android 5). I wrote the feature was introduced around Marshmallow (Android 6). Please take a look at our [factory-reset tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) and watch for the term "factory reset protection" or, in short, FRP (right at the end of the wiki). For more confirmation, take a look at [these posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=frp%20answers%3a1).

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it.  I have no idea what Marshmallow means.  But certainly, for a factory refurb, they would have a method of clearing it all out, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: Marshmallow is the name of Android 6. And you don't have to take *my* word for it – the link I gave you confirms this. Like you, my first thought was how that account connection survives a factory reset (as all data should be cleared); I didn't investigate that, but it obviously does. For details, please read [Factory Reset Protection: what you need to know](http://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know) – which is also linked from our factory-reset tag-wiki, which I already pointed out to you.